# Completely disable ? and [] globbing in zsh

Tags: zsh

zsh adds some extra globbing logic over bash:

```
$ zsh
$ echo foo[]
zsh: no matches found: foo[]
$ echo bar?
zsh: no matches found: bar?

$ bash
$ echo f[]
f[]
$ echo bar?
bar?
```

Neither of these are useful to me and make copying/typing URLs and others annoying.

I would like to disable this entirely, but I haven't found anyway to do so yet.

There are a few imperfect solutions:

- `setopt NO_NOMATCH`

This mostly works, unless your glob accidentally *does* match, like:

```
$ echo README.m?
README.md
```

- Adding quotes

This works, but doesn't work for copy+pasting snippets online and adds an extra step I need to remember when typing.

- Use `url-quote-magic` to automatically escape

This pollutes the CLI/history, and only works for pasting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`?` is a wildcard in Bash, too](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching). The difference  you are seeing occurs because in Zsh, a failed match leads to an error, whereas in Bash, it is silently ignored.

To get the Bash behavior in Zsh, add this to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```bash
unsetopt NOMATCH
```

However, I would actually recommend *not* turning it off. Silently ignoring errors is not a good thing and can even be dangerous when performing destructive operations.

For more info on this shell option, see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, this makes globbing disabled entirely. The goal is to make globbing mirror `bash` behavior, so `foo*` will glob but `foo?` will not.

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Kironide `?` is a wildcard in Bash, too, though: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching

Comment: So, what you want doesn't even seem possible in Bash either.

Comment: "Bash scans each word for the characters ‘*’, ‘?’, and ‘[’. If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern (see Pattern Matching)." https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion

Comment: thanks! I think this is exactly right. The difference is not what it globs on, but the behavior of what happens when there is no match. For zsh, a failed match leads to an error, but bash silently ignores it. `setopt NO_NOMATCH` on zsh gives us the same bash behavior. Thanks

Comment: @Kironide I updated my answer. Can you accept it now and remove your downvote?